# Client computers would not connect to the Internet through Microsoft server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet, windows

I am trying to set up a small network at work using a tower running Microsoft Server 2008 and client laptops running Windows 7. They are all connecting to the network fine, but none of the client computers can browse the internet. I have already installed ADDS, DNS and DHCP roles on the server. What else do I need to do?

Comment: What does `ip config /all` say on the client machines?  Can the server itself get out on the Internet?

Comment: How is the network connected to the internet? Can the server browse? Can you manually set a client's IP config and have it browse? Are the clients set to use DHCP? Have you actually configured DNS and DHCP, or just installed the roles?

Comment: If you're doing this for the first time on a small network then you'd really benefit from SBS 2008 rather than Microsoft Server 2008 (unless you need to do something special which SBS doesn't support).  Small Business Server just makes setting up a small Windows network that much nicer and easier.  It's probably too late to suggest that now though.

Comment: Yes, I have configured both the DNS and DHCP to work on the server.The server itself can get on the internet and browse.The clients are connecting to the .local domain, but they can't connect to the internet. The clients are all running windows 7. Is there an extra role I need to install and configure inorder for this to work?

Comment: The network is set up with a single server with one NIC connected to a  Siemens wireless modem. All clients connect through the modem's wireless capacity but the DHCP roles and DNS roles are being carried out by the the server running Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought you needed assistance setting up Internet Sharing.  Then, I kept reading and now it sounds like the other computers are just having problems connecting to the internet.

The problem is you have the Windows Server set up to route all the network traffic.  This is fine, if you were using Internet Sharing and you have this configured properly, but if all the devices are connected to the network segment that has access to the Internet, all you have to do is change the default gateway or add a static route for the default gateway on the Windows Server to route 0.0.0.0 to your wireless "modem".